# How to generate PDF using sfTCPDFPlugin in symfony 1.4?

Tags: pdf, symfony1, cakephp-2.0, symfony-1.4, tcpdf

I want to get a pdf of post details , so I installed sfTCPDFPlugin. I'm a new to it so can any one help me with this?

How to generate PDF using sfTCPDFPilugin in symfony 1.4?

Comment: As a side note, I tried TCPDF for a while, and it wasn't really working due to performance issues. DomPDF is much sleeker!

Comment: Read my question and ansewer here:


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19802383/symfony-1-4-with-tcpdf-how-to-retreive-data-from-a-database-and-show-it-as-a-p

Comment: Read my question and ansewr here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19802383/symfony-1-4-with-tcpdf-how-to-retreive-data-from-a-database-and-show-it-as-a-p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem you seems to have is to get the HTML output from your template to put it into the generated PDF. For that, you can use `getPartial` or `getPresentationFor`.

- [getPartial](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/action/sfAction.class.php#L271) will render a partial
- [getPresentationFor](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/controller/sfController.class.php#L372) will render a module/action

I recommend you to use the `getPartial`. Create a partial with the content you want to extract (and by the way, you will be able to use the same partial elsewhere if you need the same information to be viewable as html).

Assuming you create a partial called `_my_partial.php`, you can do that:

```
public function executePdf()
{
  $config = sfTCPDFPluginConfigHandler::loadConfig();

  /* put all your PDF configuration */

  $html = $this->getPartial(
    'my_partial', 
    // put in this array all variables you want to give to the partial
    array('posts' => $posts)
  );

  $pdf->writeHTMLCell(
    $w=0, 
    $h=0, 
    $x='', 
    $y='', 
    $html, 
    $border=0, 
    $ln=1, 
    $fill=0, 
    $reseth=true, 
    $align='', 
    $autopadding=true
  );

  $pdf->Output('example_001.pdf', 'I');

  throw new sfStopException();
}
```

Comment: ok .. i create partial called _my_partial.php . the things which i have to convert to pdf are in "postSuccess.php" and i create a partial and put the same codings inside that.. is it correct? Do i need to put the executePdf() inside my postAction.class.php?

Comment: Yep, put `executePdf()` inside your action class. Don't forget to replace `/* put all your PDF configuration */` with the tcpdf configuration (from the readme file).

Comment: hmm.. after putting that the contents of template is not displaying?

Comment: After what ? By calling the pdf action, it should display the pdf.

Comment: from where do i call pdf action, i have put url bottom of the postSuccess template for pdf generate..how can i call pdf action throgh that?

 <a href="<?php echo url_for('post/listAllPost') ?>">Export As PDF</a>

Comment: I guess `<a href="<?php echo url_for('post/pdf') ?>" target="_blank">Export As PDF</a>`

Answer (score 2):

Refer link for step by step to generate PDF using sfTCPDFPlugin.

http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfTCPDFPlugin/1_6_3?tab=plugin_readme

Comment: yes.. i refer that.. but im not clear about the coding they have mention on Hello World test (sfTCPDF/test).. Do i have to put in my action class of the template which i want to generate as pdf?

Comment: No this a sample url (sfTCPDF/test) to check whether this plugin is configured correctly.
If this (sfTCPDF/test) url is working in you system then only you can proceed further.